# IBM Watson Tone Analyzer API call in C#

Tags: c#, api, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson

I was trying to write a post API call to watson tone analyzer service in C#. It seems that the way to authenticate a user was changed lately from username and password to an api key.

I was trying to pass the apikey through "Authorization" header, or through a header called "apikey".. In both cases I received error 401 Unauthorized.. The other header I was using is Content-Type sets to application/json..

This calls doesn't work in a .net project nor in postman.

How can I send an API request using C#, how shell I pass the api key, and what headers should I use ?

This is the code I tried(This code returns an error of internal server error 500, while the tests I did with postman returns 401 Unauthorized):

```
   HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    string baseURL;
    string apikey= "****************"; 

    baseURL = "https://gateway-lon.watsonplatform.net/tone-analyzer/api/v3/tone?version=2017-09-21";



string postData = "{\"text\": \"" + "hi hello" + "\"}";

client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("apikey", apikey);

var response = client.PostAsync(baseURL, new StringContent(postData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")).Result;

Console.WriteLine(response);
```

The error I am receiving:

```
StatusCode: 500, ReasonPhrase: 'Internal Server Error', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  Mime-Version: 1.0
  Connection: close
  Date: Sun, 17 Feb 2019 11:37:53 GMT
  Server: AkamaiGHost
  Content-Length: 177
  Content-Type: text/html
  Expires: Sun, 17 Feb 2019 11:37:53 GMT
}
```

Comment: Why are you using the outdated WebRequest class (see remarks at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebrequest?view=netframework-4.7.2) when you already have the recommended HttpClient class? For HttpClient use `var response = client.PostAsync(baseURL, new StringContent(postData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")).Result;`

Comment: According to the documentation https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/tone-analyzer the API key is provided by setting the `Authorization` headers username to "apikey" and the password to your apikey. So `client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("apikey", apikey);`.

Comment: @ckuri I edited the code. But the result is still error 500 internal server error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this to work you need to do a proper basic authorization (see Authorization section at https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/tone-analyzer). According to [RFC 7617](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7617#section-2) basic authorization means the authorization scheme is `Basic` and the authorization parameter is username:password in Base64 encoding.

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("apikey:" + apikey)));
```

The following code worked for me:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("apikey:" + apikey)));

string postData = "{\"text\": \"" + "I am happy it finally worked" + "\"}";
var response = client.PostAsync("https://gateway-lon.watsonplatform.net/tone-analyzer/api/v3/tone?version=2017-09-21", new StringContent(postData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")).Result;
var responseContent = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

Which returned `{"document_tone":{"tones":[{"score":0.956143,"tone_id":"joy","tone_name":"Joy"},{"score":0.620279,"tone_id":"analytical","tone_name":"Analytical"}]}}`.

As a side note, I initially used the Frankfurt gateway (*gateway-fra*) and when I used my apikey for this gateway on the London gateway (*gateway-lon*) I also received server error 500 (Internal server error). For other gateways I received error 401 (Unauthorized), because the apikeys seem to be per service and gateway/location. After I deleted my ToneAnalyzer service and set up an new one this time for the London gateway, it worked. So I guess, IBM's authorization server or the Akamai load balancer they are using is a little bit wonky when you use an apikey for one gateway on another gateway.

Comment: Alternately you can use the [Watson .NET SDK](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/dotnet-standard-sdk)

Authenticating via basicauth works but the token exchange is done in the background and is not very efficient. You should be making a call to the IAM authentication URL `https://iam.bluemix.net/identity/token` and using the token in the response in your request.

https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/dotnet-standard-sdk/blob/f66b344cf7670e2bd9855a5cb9aba61884f08ce8/src/IBM.WatsonDeveloperCloud/Util/TokenManager.cs#L104-L140

The Watson .NET SDK handles this for you.